# Safari browser displaying invalid date for highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts, safari, momentjs

I am facing a date format issue in Highcharts heatmap in safari browser.

[image]

I am getting json for x-axis as follows:

```
  var duration = [];
  var utcDate = {DateUTC":["Tuesday 04-19-2016","Wednesday 04-20-2016","Thursday 04-21-2016","Friday 04-22-2016","Saturday 04-23-2016","Sunday 04-24-2016"]};
```

Here is my code to take that values for x-axis

```
_.each(utcDate, function (data) {
        duration.push(moment(data).format('dddd MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
```

So I am taking duration array and passing to x-axis as follows:

```
 xAxis: {
         categories: duration,
         opposite: true
 },
```

If I don't format with *moment.js* I am getting the output as Tuesday 04-19-2016, Wednesday 04-20-2016, etc., in the screen.

As we need to display the output as 'dddd MM/DD/YYYY' format we are using moment.js to convert.

So I dont know how to figure it out, can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: You need to tell moment.js what the input format is too, otherwise it will guess. BTW, don't post just images here, you need to state what you are actually getting. Not everyone can see the image (e.g. me!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [string + format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parse method to achieve this,

```
_.each(utcDate, function (data) {
        duration.push(moment(data, "dddd MM-DD-YYYY").format('dddd MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: actually json data of utcDate comes in any format, so at that time it wont work,right?

Comment: yes, if the format is unknown, it will be hard to parse the date. its best if the json data contains ISO compliant date format